How compute system dynamics from the solution of the Schrödinger equation?
As I understand the main problem of matter modeling is that for atoms and molecules larger than a hydrogen atom it is very difficult to find a solution to the Schrödinger equation. Let us assume that there are no restrictions on these solutions and we know the wave function for each molecule/atom. In this case, what algorithm should be used to emulate the temporal dynamics of the chemical reaction?
For example, suppose we know the solution to the Schrödinger equation for the hydrogen atom and the solution for the SO4 molecule, what do we need to do with these solutions to understand how these solutions at any given time are transformed into the solution Schrödinger equation for H2SO4?
On the one hand I know that electrons are repelled by other electrons but attracted by a proton. But in the case of solving Schrödinger's equation we don't have an electron but a probability to meet one. How can we understand how electron clouds will move by knowing this probability? Are the superposition principle and geometric calculations applicable here?
On the other hand, we realize that the solution of the Schrödinger equation contains the change of probability to meet an electron in some place with time. (Solution of Schrödinger's time equation). How can we combine this into a unified picture with the previous reasoning?

Several questions there. You need to move nuclei around to simulate say ,2H + SO4 -> H2SO4. Often you don't need to treat the nuclei in a quantum manner so w.r.t algorithms you could use either classical molecular dynamics (MD) or ab-initio (AI)MD. With respect to what electrons are doing in response to nuclear motion, you hold the nuclei fixed each step of the way and approximately solve the electronic Schrodinger equation (forget about nuclei -they become fixed point charges) with your electronic structure method of choice. Look into the Born-Oppenheimer approximation.
